# Transfer variable between viewcontrollers

Tags: objective-c, variables, viewcontroller

I have a problem with my iOS App Project. I want to transfer a value of my SearchViewController to my ResultGeneralInfoViewController. There are no bugs or issues but it doesn't work.

Here my Code in my SearchViewController.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSDictionary *item = [searchResults objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];


    ResultGeneralInfosViewController *detailViewController = [ResultGeneralInfosViewController alloc];
    detailViewController.companyName = [item objectForKey:@"companyName"];
    NSLog([item objectForKey:@"companyName"]);
}
```

ResultGeneralInfoViewController.h

```
@interface ResultGeneralInfosViewController : UIViewController {

    NSString *companyName;
}

@property NSString *companyName;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *companyNameLabel;
```

and ResultGeneralInfoViewController.m

```
@implementation ResultGeneralInfosViewController

@synthesize companyName;

//Outlets
@synthesize companyNameLabel;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    companyNameLabel.text = self.companyName;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: *"There are no bugs but it doesn't work"* seems like a contradiction in terms to me :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not initialized your ResultGeneralInfosViewController, only allocated it. Call the appropriate `init` method in order to initialize it first. For example:

```
ResultGeneralInfosViewController *detailViewController =
    [[ResultGeneralInfosViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NibName" bundle:nil];
```

Make sure you set the property once the object has been initialized.

Comment: Yes, that is also true!

Comment: I added your code to my SearchViewController.m but the result remains the same :( What is my NibName?

Comment: NibName is the name of the nib file associated with the view controller, if you have one.

Comment: So when I use Storyboards its nil?

Answer (score 1):

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, you create an instance of `ResultGeneralInfosViewController`, but you do nothing with it. If you use a navigation controller, then you should add

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```